# Deja-dup does not resume from where it left after suspend

Tags: suspend, deja-dup

I'm trying to do a backup of about 800GB of data using deja-dup. It looks like this to take about two days; when I tell deja-dup to "resume later", then suspend my laptop, then bring up deja-dup again, it does not offer me a "resume previous backup" option. From what I gather from the Internet it should automatically recognize where it left off and resume from there.

However, it always starts a full scan, then deletes all previously created archives on the backup medium, and starts all over again.

Is there a way to avoid this?

I'm running on Ubuntu 14.04

Thank you,

mischa

Answer (score 0):

It resumes from where you left off, it goes through all the files that it backed up first to ensure they did not change, then it resumes the backup.